# Specify MTU value

Tags: scapy, penetration-testing, mtu

I'm trying to pentest some IPSEC implementation for a uni project, and following [this](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01178390/document) guide I'm stuck at:

*Step 1 (common): Forging an ICMP PTB packet from the untrusted      network   The attacker first has to forge an appropriate ICMP PTB packet (a   single packet is sufficient).  This is done by eavesdropping a valid   packet from the IPsec tunnel on the untrusted network.  Then the   attacker **forges an ICMP PTB packet,** ***specifying a very small MTU value   equal or smaller than 576 with IPv4*** (resp. 1280 with IPv6).  The   attacker can use 0 for instance.  This packet spoofs the IP address   of a router of the untrusted network (in case the source IP address   is checked), and in order to bypass the IPsec protection mechanism   against blind attacks, it includes as a payload a part of the outer   IP packet that has just been eavesdropped.  This is the only packet   an attacker needs to send.  None of the following steps involve the   attacker.*

I know what MTU is, but what does the bold statement mean?

How do I set the MTU size of a packet with `scapy`?

It means that I have to set the size of a IP packet less than 576 bytes?
It's already set to `140 B`,at least it shows this with `len` command.
There's something that I didn't get right, maybe I have to set the `fragmentation`?

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about the subject, but some quick searching seems to indicate that it's referring to an [IPv6 ICMP packet with a type of 2 ("packet too big")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol_for_IPv6#Types).

Then from some poking around scapy, this appears to be how you'd create one:

```
from scapy.layers.inet6 import ICMPv6PacketTooBig

icmp_ptb = ICMPv6PacketTooBig(mtu=0)
```

Of course though, you'll need to do some testing to verify this.